# 3.8 million points in Scrabble

Tags: word, scrabble

You are playing English Scrabble **solo**, but on a 15×15 board that looks like this:

[image: 15 by 15 board, with the star in the top left corner, all square grids are Quad Word square]

The starting square is the top-left corner and all 225 squares are *quadruple word squares*. The game ends when you place all tiles on the board, and you can choose your rack's contents as you want from the remaining, unused tiles at every turn. All other rules are the same, including the 50-point bingo bonus.

Can you score at least **3.8 million points** using this board and the CSW19 lexicon? (After you do so, what is the highest score you can get?)

<sub>This puzzle came about while I was playing with [Quackle](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jasonkb/quackle) and its ability to handle custom boards.</sub>

Comment: Where did you get the number 3.8 million?

Comment: @mathlander That's what I got on my end.

Comment: You may be please to hear that Mack Meller has done a video on [exactly this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QiQQEuGoNJw)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to come up with this:

> [image: 4113296 points]

| Move | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1. 1A HYDROXY | 393266 |
| 2. H1 LOCKJAW | 376982 |
| 3. A1 (H)OSPITAL | 213042 |
| 4. A1 (HOSPITAL)IZATION | 475186 |
| 5. 1A (HYDROXYL)APATITE | 557106 |
| 6. O1 (E)THEREAL | 180274 |
| 7. O1 (ETHEREAL)ISATION | 294962 |
| 8. 12H RUNABOU(T) | 163890 |
| 9. 3D VERE(C)UND | 229426 |
| 10. 7D UNCO(W)LED | 229426 |
| 11. D5 SQ(U)iDGES | 294962 |
| 12. 15H EMBIGGE(N) | 229426 |
| 13. M1 (I)NFIRMER | 213042 |
| 14. 10H WAVEOfF(S) | 262194 |
| 15. H10 (W)I(R)E | 112 |
| Total | 4113296 |

Of course it's critical to always play 7 letters for the 16384x point bonus - the whole problem is about making those 14/15 letter words (I got 3, it's certainly possible to make 4 or 5+) and re-using high-value letters in them, which I only did well with my X...
So it's for sure possible to get 5 million, but this is already nice enough.